# ERC20, how to calculate how many tokens for crowdsale?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, crowdsale

If you look at [this](https://hashnode.com/post/the-2018-guide-to-writing-and-testing-secure-crowdsale-contracts-cjcs8dfes00apmdwthw03c2jq) article, the total tokens for crowdsale is 100 tokens and defined in the code as

```
uint256 public maxTokens = 100000000000000000000;
```

how come 100000000000000000000 becomes 100 tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Solidity only supports integer numbers, there's no natural way to represent a value like "half a token" (0.5 tokens). To work around this, ERC20 tokens use a multiplier. For US dollars, you might use a multiplier of 100, or 10^2, for 2 decimal places. In code, you'd store the number of pennies rather than the number of dollars. So $1 becomes 100 pennies, and $100 becomes 10,000 pennies. Now, half a dollar is just 50.

ERC20 tokens have a value called `decimals` which says what power of 10 you should multiply/divide things by. The ERC20 token you're looking at, like most tokens, uses `decimals = 18`, so everything is multiplied by 10^18 (a 1 with 18 zeros after it). So to represent 100 tokens, you use the value 100 * 10^18 == 10^20 == a 1 with 20 zeros after it, which is the number you see.

It's the responsibility of UI—e.g. tools like Etherscan, MetaMask, and MyEtherWallet—to take `decimals` into account and multiply and divide values as needed. So if your balance of an ERC20 token with 18 decimal places is 1000000000000000000, Etherscan will tell you you have 1 token. And if you ask MyEtherWallet to transfer 0.5 tokens, it will transfer the amount 500000000000000000.

Comment: Does `decimals = 18` mean the token value can be allowed up to 18 decimal places? Ex: 0.218392749283928378

Comment: Yes, because the value 1 would be 1/10^18 of a token.

Comment: From your answer, `10 * 10^18` isn't it supposed to be `100 * 10^18`?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I edited the answer.

Comment: OpenZeppelin documentation includes [a note on decimals](https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/tokens#a-note-on-decimals)